# If $\mathcal{L}$ is a minimal left ideal of an algebra $\mathcal{A}$, then $\mathcal{A}l=\mathcal{L}$ for all $l\in \mathcal{L}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, algebras

I am going through Hassani's 'Mathematical Physics':

- He defines an *algebra* $\mathcal{A}$ as a vector space together with a multiplication map $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{A}$.
- He defines a *left ideal* $\mathcal{L}$ as a vector subspace of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mathcal{A}\mathcal{L}\subset\mathcal{L}$.
- An ideal $\mathcal{L}$ is *minimal* if every left ideal of $\mathcal{A}$ contained in $\mathcal{L}$ coincides with $\mathcal{A}$.

He then goes on to state that a left ideal $\mathcal{L}$ is minimal if and only if $\mathcal{A}l=\mathcal{L}$ for all $l\in \mathcal{L}$. It seems to me like the forward direction of this isn't correct. For example, let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra spanned by $x,y,w$ with multiplication relations:

- $yx=y$, $xy=x$.
- $wx=wy=w$
- $xw = x$, $yw = x$, $ww=w$.

Then the only ideal is $\mathcal{A}$ iteself, which is therefore minimal. However, $\mathcal{A}w=\{x,w\}\ne \mathcal{A}$. I can't see what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: On further thinking, I believe the flaw in my 'counterexample' is that I haven't shown there isn't an invariant subspace whose basis elements are linear combinations of the elements $x, y, w$. Any hints as to how to prove the theorem though would still be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that multiplication is bilinear, the definition of minimal ideal as given characterizes the $\{0\}$ ideal.

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave is inconsistent.

$$y(xw) = yx = y$$
$$(yx)w = yw = x$$

*$\mathcal{L}$ is minimal if and only if $\mathcal{A}l=\mathcal{L}$ for all $l\in \mathcal{L}$.*

"$\Rightarrow$": If $\mathcal{A}l \subsetneq \mathcal{L}$, then $\mathcal{L}$ is not minimal. 
"$\Leftarrow$": If $l \in \mathcal{M} \subsetneq \mathcal{L}$, then $\mathcal{A}l \subseteq \mathcal{M} \neq \mathcal{L}$.

Comment: There's no associativity assumption in the OP's definition of algebra.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as @mt_ says an algebra need not be associative, for example $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the cross product as multiplication. I believe the error in my 'counterexample' is that there may be a 1 or 2 dimensional subspace which is an ideal, whose basis elements are linear combinations of $x,y,w$.

Comment: Ok. I see that here algebra is not necessarily association. Forgive me. I'm used to "algebra" referring to the associative case unless otherwise stated. What does the third bullet point mean?